# Add content after get_header

Tags: theme-development, functions, hooks, child-theme, actions

I'd like to add content directly after the `div#main` (end of `header.php`) and before `/div#main` (beginning of `footer.php`).

I'm using an own child-template (of twentythirteen), that contains only 
`style.css` and `functions.php` at the moment.

I added the following content to my functions.php

```
function myAddedStuff() {
    echo "Stuff";
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'myAddedStuff' );
add_action( 'get_footer', 'myAddedStuff' );
```

For the footer it works well, since `myAddedStuff()` is executed, before `get_footer`. But for `get_header` I'd like to execute `myAddedStuff()` **afterwards**. How can I do that.

Should I use an alternative hook? How can I easily find hooks? Is the an easy way to add contents to certain HTML commands? (e.g. use `div#main` as a "hook").

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any hook available to do so. As you are using **Child theming**, it would be best for you to take a copy of the **header.php** in the **child theme folder** and edit it as per your need.

Comment: I'd really like to avoid copy-paste of existing code. I could include it using PHP-functions, but I'm conviced that there is a provided way. I thaught there is a parameter "add_before" or "add_after" in `add_action()`, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Here are your [Filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference).
And here are your [Actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Comment: @sven I am afraid, we don't have any hooks for this case. Still let me look more into this and I am sure if we have any hooks, guys here will bring that up.

Comment: I think the add_before and add_after are features of Genesis Framework so unless you're using a Studiopress Theme you won't have access to these, but if you do, the Genesis Simple Hooks plugin should do exactly what you want.

Comment: I also thought of using jQuery. The content I'd like to add requires JavaScript, anyway. I didn't manage to use jQuery within wordpress, although it seems to be included. I added for example `<script>
$( "h1" ).remove()
</script>
` to my footer, but still all h1's are shown. I never worked with jQuery before, but this should work,...

Comment: I found out how to add jQuery to WordPress: http://fenon.de/javascript-und-jquery-in-einen-wordpress-blog-einbinden/